# How to convert EJB3 annotations to ejb-jar.xml file configuration?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I am looking for a tool which would create ejb-jar.xml configuration file from annotated EJB3 classes. Something like XDoclet, but for annotations, not tags in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if such a tool exists, but Java does come with a nice set of tools to build your own programs to process annotated classes. The [Annotation Processing Tool](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html) (APT) makes it easy to process annotations. I suspect that you use some small subset of the EJB3 annotations, so you don't need to support the entire spec. You could probably even write a quick processor to discover all of the annotations that you use and report on them, so that you had a clean list of which annotations you needed to handle.

Ant also as an [apt](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apt.html) task, which can make the process easier to run.

If you do end up taking this on, even if your implementation isn't complete (i.e. it doesn't cover every possible EJB3 annotation/option) it could be worth posting the code somewhere like [Google Code](http://code.google.com/projecthosting/) so that others can benefit, and possibly extend the tool to support more extensive options.